# What makes a strong polyadenylation signal a strong signal?

Tags: molecular-biology

I was wondering why is it that "AAUAAA" is a strong Polyadenylation signal whereas the rest of the polyadenylation signals show reduced cleavage and polyadenylation efficiency?

Comment: because enzymes, responsible for these reactions recognize _strong_ signal more readily?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just expanding on aandreev's comment.*

---

Polyadenylation is initiated by binding of CPSF (Cleavage and Polyadenylation specificity factor) after its binding to the `AAUAAA` motif.
From the introduction of [this](http://rnajournal.cshlp.org/content/7/6/920.full.pdf) article:

> CPSF (cleavage and polyadenylation specificityfactor) binds to the
>   AAUAAA hexamer via its 160-kDa subunit and possibly its 30-kDa subunit
>   (Keller et al., 1991; Murthy & Manley,1992; Jenny et al.,1994;
>   Barabino et al.,1997). CstF (cleavage  stimulation  factor) binds to
>   the U- or G/U-rich element downstream of the cleavage site, and
>   stabilizes the binding of CPSF to the AAUAAA sequence of the pre-mRNA
>   (reviewed in Colgan & Manley,1997; Wahle & Kuhn,1997).

Any alteration in the CPSF binding site will lead to reduced polyadenylation efficiency. Polyadenylation efficiency also depends on other factors such as [secondary structure](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/2/446.long) and presence of proximal [CstF sites](http://www.frontiersin.org/Journal/DownloadFile/1/3450/44311/1/21/fendo-04-00053_pdf).